# Git: Cloning repo with parent hierarchy

Tags: git

I have a `~/git` directory, into which i clone everything i work on.
To keep things simple and organized, i mirror the remote directory structure.
So `https://gitlab.com/ajak/tuir` would be cloned in `~/git/gitlab.com/ajak/tuir`.

I created a bash script which broke under different circumstances and i wondered, if i was just missing the right command.

Is there a way to do this elegantly with one command, instead of creating this structure by hand?

Edit: it seems i forgot to mention some information.
Sometimes i want to clone via ssh and sometimes https.
So the urls could be `git@gitlab.com:ajak/tuir.git` or `https://gitlab.com/ajak/tuir.git`.
I guess i'll stick to a script, once i can dig it up on the right computer.

Comment: Sure there is! Though what have you tried so far. Also, it seems it is very specific to your bash script which is maintaining this directory hierarchy - so your question doesn't sound like anyone would be able to answer in a generic way. If you show what your bash script is failing at, maybe you can get help from others on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Bash you may want to try something like

```
FOO="gitlab.com/ajak/tuir" bash -c 'git clone https://$FOO $FOO'
```

Or place a function in your `.bashrc`

```
function foo() {
    git clone https://$1 $1
}
```

and call `foo gitlab.com/ajak/tuir`.

Comment: Thank you, using a function i can even switch into the directory after cloning. That is a great idea.