# Git clone to directory taken from URI

Tags: git

I wonder if there is a shorthand for this command:

`git clone git@gitlab.com:organisation/devops/devops-utils.git organisation/devops/devops-utils`

The idea is to keep the directory structure when cloning multiple projects from multiple organizations. It's not uncommon for two companies to have projects that share common names, so keeping separate directories for every company seems like a reasonable thing to do. Writing a bash alias for this is not too difficult, but I wonder if there is some way to do that using just git. Is there?

P.S. Of course I googled, but to no avail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: Cloning repo with parent hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58755727/git-cloning-repo-with-parent-hierarchy)

Comment: "I wonder if there is some way to do that using just git". Your hyperlink is about a bash solution. As far as I know there is no functionality like I described baked in git itself.

Comment: Nop. `git clone <URL>` clones into a directory named by [**the last path component** from the URL](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt-ltdirectorygt).